# Eliminating functions from system of PDE in Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

*Mathematica* users,

Let's see an example of three PDEs:

How can I eliminate variables `q1[x,y,z]` and `q2[x,y,z]` from a system of three PDEs in *Mathematica*. In final form, I need just one equation in function of `p1[x,y,z]`. Why this code is working well when I want to eliminate `q1` and `q2` from `a1`, `a2` and `a3`, but doesn't work when I want to eliminate `q1` and `q2` from `a1`, `a2`, `a3` and `a4`?

```
 a1=A1*D[p1[x,y,z],{z,2}]-A2*(D[p1[x,y,z],{x,2}]+
    D[p1[x,y,z],{y,2}]+D[q1[x,y,z], {x,1}]+D[q2[x,y,z],{y,1}])==0;


 a2=A9*(A2*D[(D[q1[x,y,z],{x,1}]+D[q2[x,y,z],{y,1}]),{x,1}]+A2*(D[q1[x,y,z],{x,2}]+
    D[q1[x,y,z],{y,2}]))-A4*(D[p1[x,y,z],{x,1}]+q1[x,y,z])-A8*D[q1[x,y,z],{z,2}]==0;


 a3=A9*(A6*D[(D[q1[x,y,z],{x,1}]+D[q1[x,y,z],{y,1}]),{y,1}]+A7*(D[q2[x,y,z],{x,2}]+
    D[q1[x,y,z],{y,2}]))-A1*(D[p1[x,y,z],{y,1}]+q2[x,y,z])-A4*D[q2[x,y,z],{z,2}]==0;

 a4=A09*A006*D[(D[q2[x,y,z],{x,1}]+D[q2[x,y,z],{y,1}]),{y,1}]+A004*D[q1[x,y,z],{z,2}]==0;

 rule=Flatten[{#[x,y,z]->#,Derivative[n_,m_,o_][#][x_,y_,z_]-># x^n y^m z^o}&/@{p1,q1,q2}];

 invRule=(x_->z_):>z Derivative[Sequence@@x][p1];

 ww1=Eliminate[{a1,a2,a4}/.rule,{q1,q2}]/.(x_==y_)->(x-y);

 ww2=CoefficientRules[ww1,{x,y,z}];

 t=Total[ww2/.p1->1/.invRule]==0;

 t
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that "working" example really works. You seem to replace mixed derivatives of the qj's with qj (not a derivative thereof) times monomials. Is that really correct for your example? (Are your qj functions known to be exponentials of sums of squares?)

Comment: Crikey. I think I got something that works. Surprised am I. (Or maybe just seeing things.) Will post as response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We start with the given differential polynomials.

```
a1 = A1*D[p1[x, y, z], {z, 2}] - 
   A2*(D[p1[x, y, z], {x, 2}] + D[p1[x, y, z], {y, 2}] + 
      D[q1[x, y, z], {x, 1}] + D[q2[x, y, z], {y, 1}]);
a2 = A9*(A2*
       D[(D[q1[x, y, z], {x, 1}] + D[q2[x, y, z], {y, 1}]), {x, 1}] + 
      A2*(D[q1[x, y, z], {x, 2}] + D[q1[x, y, z], {y, 2}])) - 
   A4*(D[p1[x, y, z], {x, 1}] + q1[x, y, z]) - 
   A8*D[q1[x, y, z], {z, 2}];
a3 = A9*(A6*
       D[(D[q1[x, y, z], {x, 1}] + D[q1[x, y, z], {y, 1}]), {y, 1}] + 
      A7*(D[q2[x, y, z], {x, 2}] + D[q1[x, y, z], {y, 2}])) - 
   A1*(D[p1[x, y, z], {y, 1}] + q2[x, y, z]) - 
   A4*D[q2[x, y, z], {z, 2}];
a4 = A09*A006*
    D[(D[q2[x, y, z], {x, 1}] + D[q2[x, y, z], {y, 1}]), {y, 1}] + 
   A004*D[q1[x, y, z], {z, 2}];
```

Take three prolongations (that is, derivatives with respect to each variable in turn).

```
diffpolys = {a1, a2, a3, a4};
vars = {x, y, z};
d2 = Join[diffpolys, Flatten[Outer[D, diffpolys, vars]]];
d3 = Union[Join[d2, Flatten[Outer[D, d2, vars]]]];
d4 = Union[Join[d3, Flatten[Outer[D, d3, vars]]]];

pvars = Cases[Variables[d4], Derivative[__][p1][__]];
qvars = Cases[Variables[d4], Derivative[__][q1 | q2][__]];

Length[d4]
(* Out[135]= 80 *)

Length[qvars]
(* Out[136]= 110 *)
```

110 unknowns in 80 polynomials is not promising. Undaunted, we forge ahead.

```
Timing[
 gb = GroebnerBasis[d4, pvars, qvars, 
    MonomialOrder -> EliminationOrder, 
    CoefficientDomain -> RationalFunctions];]

(* Out[137]= {7.540000, Null} *)
```

So here it is.

```
gb
```

{A006*A09*A1*A4*Derivative[0, 1, 2][p1][x, y, z] + 
     A006*A09*A1*A8*Derivative[0, 1, 4][p1][x, y, z] - 
     A006*A09*A2*A4*Derivative[0, 3, 0][p1][x, y, z] + 
     ((-A006)*A09*A2*A8 - A006*A09*A1*A2*A9)*Derivative[0, 3, 2][p1][
         x, y, z] + 
  A006*A09*A2^2*A9*Derivative[0, 5, 0][p1][x, y, z] + 
     (A006*A09*A1*A4 - A004*A2*A4)*
   Derivative[1, 0, 2][p1][x, y, z] + 
     (A006*A09*A1*A8 + A004*A1*A2*A9)*Derivative[1, 0, 4][p1][x, y, 
         z] - A006*A09*A2*A4*Derivative[1, 2, 0][p1][x, y, z] + 
     ((-A006)*A09*A2*A8 - A006*A09*A1*A2*A9 - A004*A2^2*A9)*
       Derivative[1, 2, 2][p1][x, y, z] + A006*A09*A2^2*A9*
       Derivative[1, 4, 0][p1][x, y, z] + 
     ((-A006)*A09*A2*A8 - 2*A006*A09*A1*A2*A9)*
       Derivative[2, 1, 2][p1][x, y, z] + 3*A006*A09*A2^2*A9*
       Derivative[2, 3, 0][p1][x, y, z] + 
     ((-A006)*A09*A2*A8 - 2*A006*A09*A1*A2*A9 - A004*A2^2*A9)*
       Derivative[3, 0, 2][p1][x, y, z] + 3*A006*A09*A2^2*A9*
       Derivative[3, 2, 0][p1][x, y, z] + 2*A006*A09*A2^2*A9*
       Derivative[4, 1, 0][p1][x, y, z] + 2*A006*A09*A2^2*A9*
       Derivative[5, 0, 0][p1][x, y, z]}

This does seem to match your result. The fact that I do not understand why your method works is no indication of shortcoming (other than perhaps on my part).